# Cannot do `npm i tmi.js` on any computer. Can I download manually or in a different way?

Tags: node.js, npm

When I try to do `npm i tmi.js` / `npm i tmi.js --save` it gives some warnings and problems.

I tried deleting all cache, downloading on a different pc but nothing is working. Screenshot of the error:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: you are fine, its just warnings

Comment: @Egor not actually, this NPM doesnt working thus way.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Thanks to Dist and Alca From TwitchDeveloper Discord channel. These [messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Bzd4.png) helped to fix this problem. The solution is to:

- Run `npm init` to create the missing `package.json`
- Use `npm audit` to diagnose the vulnerabilities and `npm audit fix` to attempt a fix

  - Or install `twitch-js@^1.2.17` instead of `tmi.js` (for the time being) as it works as well and has no vulnerabilities